# How Create 64 byte public and 32 byte private key Using ECDH encryption swift?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, key, ecdh

I have to protect my lock from MITM (i.e man in the middle attack). For that i have to integrate `ECDH encryption`. I have no knowledge related to this. Please help me how do i create `64 bytes public` and `32 byte private` key. below are the code i'm trying

```
var publicKeySec, privateKeySec: SecKey?
let keyattribute = [
    kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 256
    ] as CFDictionary

SecKeyGeneratePair(keyattribute, &publicKeySec, &privateKeySec)


var error:Unmanaged<CFError>?
if let publicCfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKeySec!, &error) {
    let data:Data = publicCfdata as Data
    print(data)
    let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString()
    print(b64Key)
}

if let privateCfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(privateKeySec!, &error) {
    let data:Data = privateCfdata as Data
    print(data)
    let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString()
    print(b64Key)
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you able to resolve this? This is related to Apple Wallet In App Provisioning?